# Possible error in Marion and Thornton's Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, conventions, rotation

I was going over my notes on classical mechanics and just started to review rotation matrices which is the first topic the book starts with. On page 3

[image]

The rotation matrix associated with 1.2a and 1.2b is

\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}

but when I try to derive the matrix by following the unit vectors $\hat i$ and $\hat j$

I get

\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}

The one that the book derives would be clockwise rotation, and the one I got would be for counter-clockwise rotation correct?

Comment: There are two points of view : The point $\: \mathrm P\:$ is rotated clockwise and the coordinate system remains fixed or the coordinate system  is rotated anticlockwise and the point  $\: \mathrm P\:$ remains fixed.

Comment: Yea I was just realizing that. I think what the book does is rotate the coordinate system counter-clockwise but then it measures lengths in the new coordinate system. Meaning that they effectively changed basis while the matrix I was computing was in the old basis. Is it correct to think of it in this way?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: In two dimensions you could solve your problems with complex numbers. Suppose you want to rotate the point $\:\mathrm P : z=x+iy\:$  by an angle $\:\theta\:$ to a new position $\: \mathrm P' : z'=x'+iy'\:$. Don't bother yourself if clock- or anticlock- wise, the sign of $\:\theta\:$ cares for this.
\begin{align}
z'=e^{i\theta}z\: \Longrightarrow \:x'+iy' & =\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)\left(x+iy\right)
\tag{01}\\
&=\left(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta \right)+i\left(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta \right)
\nonumber
\end{align}

Comment: ...so
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     x'\\
     y'
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
     \sin\theta & \hphantom{-}\cos\theta
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     x\\
     y
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

Comment: The matrix in (02) is a rotation one. But looking with the other point of view it's the coordinates transformation matrix under rotation of the coordinate system by an angle $\:\phi=-\theta\:$ keeping the point $\:\mathrm P\:$ fixed
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     x'\\
     y'
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cos\phi & \sin\phi\:\\
     -\sin\phi & \cos\phi\:
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     x\\
     y
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much. This has cleared it up a lot for me.

Comment: You can either rotate the coordinate system or the vector.  These two choices are referred to as passive and active rotations, respectively.  See Wikipedia and Goldstein, Classical Mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the rotation matrix by finding the direction cosines defined as $\lambda_{i,j}=\cos(x'_{i},x_{j})$ so:

$\lambda_{11}=\cos(x'_{1},x_{1})=\cos\theta$

$\lambda_{12}=\cos(x'_{1},x_{2})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=\sin\theta$

$\lambda_{21}=\cos(x'_{2},x_{1})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)=-\sin\theta$

$\lambda_{22}=\cos(x'_{2},x_{2})=\cos\theta$

The book is right.

Comment: Sorry but your post doesn't explain anything. My concern is that the book presents a rotation matrix that seems to represent clockwise rotation while what they illustrate is counter-clockwise rotation; is this incorrect?

Comment: Oh, the problem  the book represents a rotation from $(x'_{1},x'_{2})$ system to $(x_{1},x_{2})$ system.

Comment: Note that your rotation matrix, which is the inverse of book's matrix, represents the rotation from $(x_{1},x_{2})$ to $(x'_{1},x'_{2})$, maybe that is your confusion.

Comment: Correct, I'm going from $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ to $(x'_{1}, x'_{2})$ so shouldn't that transformation be $\begin{pmatrix} x'_{1} \\ x'_{2} \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ \end{pmatrix} $?

Comment: To do what the book is doing wouldn't it be $\begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x'_{1} \\ x'_{2} \\ \end{pmatrix} $?